# Combining histogram with "categorized" x-variable plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to combina "normal" histogram of a binary variable (with fractions on the y-axis) with a second histogram (preferably differentiated from the first by its alpha value (transparency)) which depicts specific categories of the x-axis.

See the following code for an example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = ..count../sum(..count..))) +
geom_histogram()
```

Of the numeric x-variable, I create factor variable:

```
mtcars$mpgCat <- ifelse(mtcars$mpg <= 15, 0,
                    ifelse(mtcars$mpg > 15 & mtcars$mpg <=25, 1,
                           ifelse(mtcars$mpg > 25 & mtcars$mpg < 35, 2, NA)))
mtcars$mpgCat <- factor(mtcars$mpgCat, levels = c(0:2), labels = c("<=15", ">15", "<35"))
```

The factor variable results in a histogram when specifying stat="count":

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpgCat, y = ..count../sum(..count..))) +
  geom_histogram(stat="count")
```

Is there some way to combine both histograms, preferrably with the latter being transparent, so that the numeric x-values overlap directly with the respective bars of the factorvariable? Of course, it would be best if the bars of the factor variable would have a width representative of the fraction of the numeric x-variable they "represent". However, the latter might be overly complicated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think one way would be to try and play with `binwidth`, for example: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = ..count../sum(..count..)))+
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 10, fill = 'blue')+
    geom_histogram()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out ggplot2 does most of what you want automagically, if you know how to ask. I created two histogram layers. The first has a manually selected number of bins (`bins=10`) and manually tweaked `boundary=0.25` to get the bin boundaries to line up visually. The second has manually created exact bin boundaries (`breaks=c(10, 15, 25, 35)`) selected to exactly match your three categories of `mpgCat`. It also has transparency set for the whole layer (`alpha=0.4`). You may also be interested in the `cut()` function for splitting continuous variables into factors.

```
library(ggplot2)

mtcars$mpgCat = cut(mtcars$mpg, c(10, 15, 25, 35))

p = ggplot(data=mtcars) +
    geom_histogram(aes(x=mpg, y=..count../sum(..count..)), 
                   bins=20, boundary=0.25) +
    geom_histogram(aes(x=mpg, y =..count../sum(..count..), fill=mpgCat), 
                   alpha=0.4, breaks=c(10, 15, 25, 35))

ggsave("histgram.png", plot=p, height=4, width=6, dpi=150)
```

### [image]

Please note that this plot could be quite misleading; The red and blue bars each represent 20% of the data, but the area of the blue bar is fully twice that of the red!